# sphinx overrided template block not recognized

Tags: templates, jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm attempting to add a link to an icon I used to the footer of my doc page, but I can't seem to figure out how to copy this link. I'm following [this](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html#jinja-sphinx-templating-primer) tutorial but haven't had any luck. I've created a file `_templates/layout.html`:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block footer %}
    <li><a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0">CC BY 3.0</a></li>
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

then in my `conf.py` I do

```
templates_path = ['_templates']

# ...

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
```

The problem is that when I build, nothing extra shows up in the footer of my page. I initially thought sphinx just wasn't finding my file, but if I change `{% extends "!layout.html" %}` to `{% extends "layout.html" %}` I get the error

```
Running Sphinx v1.3.1
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 30 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
preparing documents... done
writing output... [  3%] dev/conventions
Exception occurred:
  File "C:\...\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 389,
 in __getitem__
    if self._queue[-1] != key:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
The full traceback has been saved in c:\...\appdata\local\temp\1\sphi
nx-err-tjhk_m.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message c
an be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphin
x/issues>. Thanks!
```

So I know sphinx see's my file, but it doesn't seem to write anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I ended up having was I was overwriting the *wrong* file, while `layout.html` did implement a *footer* block, it was not the block I was looking to add to. Instead sphinx_rtd_theme has a `footer.html` file, which I ended up overwriting instead and everything worked as intended.